# swfObject embed attribute and external interface

Tags: html, flash, externalinterface

i know that swfObject still works with html5, but since the code is much shorter, and because only 1% of my visitors use older browsers, I would like to use the embed attribute instead. But will the externalInterface still work?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? SWFObject only handles the embeding of the flash.

Comment: External Interface will work with older browsers. I recommend using dynamic publishing with SWFObject and using both embed and object tags( id and name attributes respectively). Have a look at [this article](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/external-interface/) and test the sample on the browser you want to target